# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') cannot be resolved

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native.
I'm studying my own project and got problem, hope you guys can help me as detail as possible.
The idea is when I click on 'Daily Mix 1' album on HomeScreen, it will navigate to DailyMix1 screen. But it shows the error ***Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')*** as the image below. The component Album1 is inside the HomeScreen, and the TouchableOpacity contains navigating function is inside Album1.

**HomeScreen**

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView vertical={true} style={styles.scrollViewSetting}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#783C50', 'black']}
        start={{ x: 0.5, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
      >
        <View style={styles.screenCover}>
          <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} translucent={true} backgroundColor='transparent' />
          <View>
            <FontAwesome
              name="cog"
              size={24}
              color="#969696"
              style={styles.settingIcon}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("SettingsScreen");
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Album1 />
            <Album2 />
          </View>
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

**Album1**

```
const Album1 = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>
          Made for you
        </Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View style={styles.listAlbum}>
          {/*  */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => { navigation.navigate("DailyMix1") }}>
            <View>
              <AlbumItem
                name="Daily Mix 1"
                image={album_image_1}
                author="Shawn Mendes, Ed Sheeran"
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {/*  */}
          <View>
            <AlbumItem
              name="Daily Mix 2"
              image={album_image_2}
              author="The Chainsmokers, Clean Bandit"
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**StackNavigation**

```
const HomeStackNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                }}
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen
                options={{
                    title: '',
                    headerTransparent: true,
                    headerBackTitle: ' ',
                    headerTintColor: 'white',
                    gestureEnabled: false,
                }}
                name="DailyMix1" component={DailyMix1} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

**DailyMix1**

```
const DailyMix1 = ({ navigation = this.props.navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.background}>
            <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} translucent={true} />
            <View style={styles.firstView}>
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={['#52524B', '#121212']}
                    style={styles.linearGradient}
                    start={{ x: 0.95, y: 0.3 }}
                    end={{ x: 0.95, y: 0.95 }}
                >
                    <Image source={require('../components/assets/album1/album_image_1.png')} style={styles.imageStyle} />
                    <Text style={styles.nameStyle}>
                        Daily Mix 1
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subNameStyle}>
                        MADE FOR YOU
                    </Text>
                </LinearGradient>

            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

[image: Shown Error]

I tried adding `{ ...this.props }` in `<Album1 />` and changing `naviation.navigate` in `Album1.js` to `this.props.navigation.navigate` but it produced same error.

Hope you guys can help me, and show me where to put any corrections. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass navigation prop to the `Album1` Component

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView vertical={true} style={styles.scrollViewSetting}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#783C50', 'black']}
        start={{ x: 0.5, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
      >
        <View style={styles.screenCover}>
          <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} translucent={true} backgroundColor='transparent' />
          <View>
            <FontAwesome
              name="cog"
              size={24}
              color="#969696"
              style={styles.settingIcon}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("SettingsScreen");
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Album1 navigation={navigation}/> // Pass Navigation to Album1 as a prop
            <Album2 />
          </View>
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that navigation is equal props.navigation, you can try it. It works.

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
      return (
        <ScrollView vertical={true} style={styles.scrollViewSetting}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['#783C50', 'black']}
            start={{ x: 0.5, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
          >
            <View style={styles.screenCover}>
              <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} translucent={true} backgroundColor='transparent' />
              <View>
                <FontAwesome
                  name="cog"
                  size={24}
                  color="#969696"
                  style={styles.settingIcon}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("SettingsScreen");
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <View>
                <Album1 navigation={navigation} />
                <Album2 navigation={navigation} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </LinearGradient>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    };
```